# Read local JSON file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to load json file in javascript.
I found a link below.
http://www.askyb.com/javascript/load-json-file-locally-by-js-without-jquery/

test1.json

```
data = '[{"name" : "Harry","age": 32.12}]';
```

test2.json

```
data = '[
    {
        "name" : "Harry",
        "age": "32"
    }
]';
```

The code in the link above works with test1.json, but with test2.json,
I have got error below.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at load (myscript.js:2)
    at onload (test.html:8)
```

What's the reason?

myscript.js

```
function load() {
    var mydata = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(mydata[0].name);
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Load JSON</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test1.json"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="load()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show the code that you are using?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: Those things that are indicated as `.json` are not, in fact, JSON files.

Comment: Then, why does it work with test1.json? test1.json != test2.json?

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work, you are taking a string with newlines and trying to convert it to JSON? JSON.parse won't understand those newline. While in the first case it's okay.

Comment: So what can I do in this case?
I want to load a big json file over 600000 rows.
Write all of them in one line?

Comment: Your files are JavaScript files and should be named `test1.js` / `test2.js`. Depending on how strict your browser / server mime-types are, you may have trouble getting browsers to interpret a `.json` file as JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to have a varaible span multiple lines, you need to use back ticks not single quotes

```js
let data1 = '[{"name" : "Harry","age": 32.12}]';
let data2 = `[
    {
        "name" : "Harry",
        "age": "32"
    }
]`;
let JSONdata1 = JSON.parse(data1);
let JSONdata2 = JSON.parse(data2);
console.log(JSONdata1 );
console.log(JSONdata2 );
```

Comment: Sorry, I misread the post. Updated to reflect the use of JSON on multiple lines

Comment: Excellent. Happy to help

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this is part of the ES2015 specification and will not work in IE. You can read more on Template Literals here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals